# R: How can I create a line graph with shades in between each point indicating the percent change?

Tags: r, graph

The goal of this is to implement the graph into a Shiny Dashboard that displays month to month net worth. The y-axis would be $, and the x axis would be any given month. I’m looking for something like this:[image]

I’ve searched a ton of ggplot documentation, but couldn’t find anything.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple version that could be tweaked for aesthetics but has all the components:

```
library(tidyverse) # using ggplot2 and dplyr

df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A","B"), each = 2),
                 year = c(2003, 2013),
                 val = c(15,20,25,20))

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(change_dir = last(val) > first(val),
         change = scales::percent(last(val) / first(val) - 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, val,label = val)) +
  geom_area(aes(fill = change_dir)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(vjust = -0.5) +
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(group, change),
            aes(x = 2008, y = 3, label = change)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2003, 2013)) +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

[image]